# Variable assignment in recursive make call

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a simple Makefile as below:

```
VAR += 4 5 6

default:
    @echo "$(VAR)"
a:
    VAR="1 2 3" make
b:
    make VAR="1 2 3"
```

`make a` works as expected and print `1 2 3 4 5 6`, but `make b` only print `1 2 3`. I thought this two variants are identical.

The question is: Why is that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote from the GNU make manual:

> If a variable has been set with a command argument, then ordinary
>   assignments in the makefile are ignored.

You can change that with the `override`directive:

```
 override VAR += 4 5 6
```